# Check Monitor mode availability

Tags: ubuntu

I'm using a Qualcomm QCA9377 network Adapter.when i run

> airmon-ng start wlan0

it says that it enabled monitor mode on wlan0 making it wlan0mon
but when I run

> airodump-ng wlan0mon

It doesn't show any results. Although there are plenty of wifi networks around me

So how can i make sure my network card supports monitor mode?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with your interface in monitor mode, make sure you are in proximity to a few Wi-Fi networks so that the adapter has a chance of succeeding. Then, in a terminal window, type `**aireplay-ng --test wlan0mon**` to start the packet injection test.

***Output #1***

> aireplay-ng --test wlan0mon
>
> 12:47:05  Waiting for beacon frame (BSSID: AA:BB:CC:DD:EE) on channel
>   7 12:47:05  Trying broadcast probe requests... 12:47:06  Injection is
>   working! 12:47:07  Found 1 AP
>
> 12:47:07  Trying directed probe requests... 12:47:07  AA:BB:CC:DD:EE -
>   channel: 7 - 'Dobis' 12:47:08  Ping (min/avg/max):
>   0.891ms/15.899ms/32.832ms Power: -21.72 12:47:08  29/30:  96%

***Output #2***

> aireplay-ng --test wlan0mon
>
> 21:47:18  Waiting for beacon frame (BSSID: AA:BB:CC:DD:EE) on channel
>   6 21:47:18  Trying broadcast probe requests... 21:47:20  No Answer...
>   21:47:20  Found 1 AP
>
> 21:47:20  Trying directed probe requests... 21:47:20 
>   74:85:2A:97:5B:08 - channel: 6 - 'Dobis' 21:47:26   0/30:   0%

If you get Output #1 , well, your network card **supports** monitor-mode. if your output is alike Output #2, sadly, your network card **doesn't support** monitor mode.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the confusion is. We all thinking it has made another port of monitor mode WiFi. But it is the wlan0 you have to use instead of wlan0mon. Nowadays airmon-ng is working like that. But first you have to use `ifconfig` and `iwconfig`  to execute monitor mode. Hope this helps.